# Primavera Integration API cannot create user license

Tags: java, primavera

I'm trying trying to create a user, which work like a charm. But I cannot assign he/she a userlicense. I get the error message. **Field ObjectId has not been loaded or set.** What Field ObjectId has not been set?

```
    User user = new User(_sessionHelper.getSession());
    user.setName(importResourcesData.getSsoID());
    user.setPersonalName(importResourcesData.getFirstName() + " " + importResourcesData.getLastName());
    User.setEmailAddress(importResourcesData.getEmailAdress());
    user.setPassword(importResourcesData.getSsoID(), importResourcesData.getSsoID());
    user.setAllResourceAccessFlag(false);
    user.setGlobalProfileObjectId(getDefaultGlobalSecurityProfile());

    ObjectId userId = user.create(); //WORKS!!!
   
      BOIterator<UserLicense> loadResources = _sessionHelper.getElm().loadUserLicenses(new String[]{"LicenseType"}, "LicenseType = 'Timesheets'", null);
      Userlicense ul = loadResources.next();
      //This Fails!
      user.createUserLicense(ul);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, the integration API is structured such that once you call create or update on an object, you should not continue to use the object.  Instead, you should read a new object from the API and use that new object going forward.  In your case you would add something like this after the call to `user.create()`

```
final User user2 = User.load(_sessionHelper.getSession(), null, userId);
```

Then you would use `user2` in place of `user` in the call to `createUserLicense`

```
user2.createUserLicense(ul);
```